# Rearrangements of Dirichlet Eta Function

Tags: sequences-and-series, analytic-number-theory

I was wondering if explicit closed forms for rearrangements of $\eta(s)$, for $s$ such that the series is not absolutely convergent, are useful in studying the Dirichlet $\eta$ function.

I am asking this specific question because although we learn about rearrangements of conditionally convergent series, I haven't seen any good applications of such facts, in particular for rearrangements we can compute explicitly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Riemann's theorem any conditionally convergent series can be rearranged to converge to any given value (or diverge). So, in general, there is not much you could do. However, if you impose a particular order of summation (i.e. the principal value), and define $\eta(s)$ with this order of summation, then, in principle, you could derive some useful facts. For example, the [Eisenstein series](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EisensteinSeries.html) is not absolutely convergent for $r = 2$, but if we impose a particular order of summation, we can obtain its Fourier expansion which will be absolutely convergent for $r = 2$.